# What are the effective differences between child_process.fork and cluster.fork?

Tags: node.js

I understand that cluster.fork will allow for multiple processes to listen on the same port(s), what I also want to know is how much additional overhead is there in supporting this when some of your workers are not listeners/handlers for the tcp service?

I have a service that I also want to launch a couple of workers.. ex: 2 web service listener processes, and 3 worker instances.  Is it best to use cluster for them all, or would cluster for the 2 web services, and child_process for the workers be better?

I don't know the internals in node, but think it would be nice for myself and others to have a better understanding of which route to take given different needs.  For now, I'm using cluster for all the processes.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`cluster.fork` is implemented on top of `child_process.fork`. The extra stuff that `cluster.fork` brings is that, it will enable you to listen on a shared port. If you don't want it, just use `child_process.fork`. So yeah, use cluster for web servers and child_process for workers.

Answer (score 0):

Cluster is a module of Node.js that contains sets of functions and properties that helps the developers for forking processes through which they can take advantage of the multi-core system.
With the cluster module, the creation and sharing of child processes and several parts become easy. In a single thread, the individual instance of node.js runs specifically and to take advantage of various ecosystems, a cluster of node.js is launched, to distribute the load.

A developer can access Operating System functionalities by the child_process module, this happens by running any system command inside a child process. The child process input streams can be controlled and the developer can also listen to the output stream.
A child process can be easily spun using Node’s child_process module and these child processes can easily communicate with each other with the help of a messaging system