# How to send a message to a child process created using fork()?

Tags: node.js

I have a parent process and it forks some number of child processes. I'm looking for some way how child processes can communicate to parent process using messages. I try to send pid of parent to child process and it would be great if I can send message back using parent's pid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just in case someone is using IPC and JSON serialization, what I observed is that it sends message from Child-to-Parent but not Parent-to-Child using `send()` function. When I used `fork` instead of `spawn`, it started sending messages in both ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [child_process.fork()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) then when you create a new fork a [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process) is returned.

And according to the documentation:

> The returned ChildProcess will have an additional communication
>   channel built-in that allows messages to be passed back and forth
>   between the parent and child. See child.send() for details.
>
> It is important to keep in mind that spawned Node.js child processes
>   are independent of the parent with exception of the IPC communication
>   channel that is established between the two. Each process has it's own
>   memory, with their own V8 instances. Because of the additional
>   resource allocations required, spawning a large number of child
>   Node.js processes is not recommended.

And here's the documention for [child.send](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback)

Where you can find this piece of code:

For example, in the parent script:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const n = cp.fork(`${__dirname}/sub.js`);

n.on('message', (m) => {
  console.log('PARENT got message:', m);
});

n.send({ hello: 'world' });
```

And then the child script, 'sub.js' might look like this:

```
process.on('message', (m) => {
  console.log('CHILD got message:', m);
});

process.send({ foo: 'bar' });
```

Comment: if I fork more that 1 child process and I'm going to communicate with them, should I consider to use `cluster` module ?

Comment: @NikitaLuparev this answer might help make your decision http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367607/what-are-the-effective-differences-between-child-process-fork-and-cluster-fork